# Error in JPA & EJB

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0

I'm a newbie in JPA and EJB. Tried JPA and EJB apps seperately and went fine. But got error while using them together.

This is the error (log) I got while using JPA with EJB 3 (JBoss 7 AS server) in eclipse IDE.

can anyone help me to fix it.

```
 11:43:43,735 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS011402: Starting Persistence Unit Service 'SampleEAR.ear#Student'
    11:43:43,781 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."SampleEAR.ear"."SampleEJB.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."SampleEAR.ear"."SampleEJB.jar".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "SampleEJB.jar" of deployment "SampleEAR.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011047: Component class ejb.MyBean for component MyBean has errors: 
    JBAS011428: Cannot inject RESOURCE_LOCAL container managed EntityManagers using @PersistenceContext
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.handle(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:169)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.processClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:162)
        at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:155)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        ... 5 more

    11:43:43,816 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (MSC service thread 1-14) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
    11:43:43,820 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (MSC service thread 1-14) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.0.1.Final}
    11:43:43,821 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-14) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
    11:43:43,822 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-14) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
    11:43:43,835 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-14) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
        name: Student
        ...]
    11:43:43,837 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /SampleWAR
    11:43:43,924 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (MSC service thread 1-14) HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
    11:43:43,925 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-14) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."SampleEAR.ear#Student": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."SampleEAR.ear#Student": Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Student] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        ... 3 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Specified JDBC Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver class not found
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:104)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:234)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @16e3ecd (roots: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_09]
        at org.hibernate.internal.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:101)
        ... 23 more

    11:43:44,141 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "SampleEAR.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SampleEAR.ear\".\"SampleEJB.jar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SampleEAR.ear\".\"SampleEJB.jar\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"SampleEJB.jar\" of deployment \"SampleEAR.ear\"","jboss.persistenceunit.\"SampleEAR.ear#Student\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"SampleEAR.ear#Student\": Failed to start service"},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean]"]}
    11:43:44,166 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl] (Finalizer) HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [null]
    11:43:44,168 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SampleEJB.jar in 27ms
    11:43:44,168 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SampleWAR.war in 27ms
    11:43:44,171 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment SampleEAR.ear in 31ms
    11:43:44,172 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
    JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
          service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean.ValidatorFactory, service jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean.Validator] 
    JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."SampleEAR.ear"."SampleEJB.jar".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."SampleEAR.ear"."SampleEJB.jar".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "SampleEJB.jar" of deployment "SampleEAR.ear"
          service jboss.persistenceunit."SampleEAR.ear#Student": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."SampleEAR.ear#Student": Failed to start service

    11:43:44,175 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SampleEAR.ear\".\"SampleEJB.jar\".INSTALL" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"SampleEAR.ear\".\"SampleEJB.jar\".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment \"SampleEJB.jar\" of deployment \"SampleEAR.ear\"","jboss.persistenceunit.\"SampleEAR.ear#Student\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"SampleEAR.ear#Student\": Failed to start service"},"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean.ValidatorFactoryjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean]","jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBeanMissing[jboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean.Validatorjboss.naming.context.java.comp.SampleEAR.SampleEJB.MyBean]"]}}}
```

Comment: How are you building your EAR? Including the driver in the Eclipse build path alone is useless unless the JAR is also getting built into the EAR that you are deploying too JBoss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the stack trace you are using MS SQL server.

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver from [Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @16e3ecd (roots: C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules)]`

This line indicate that the JDBC driver for MS SQL server is not in your classpath. Or packaged with the `SampleEAR.ear` file.

I suggest you add it to the build path of your project via whatever the IDE you are using so it will be packaged in the `.ear` file.

EDIT:

In that case in your config xml change the driver class to `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver` The class you have added is for MS SQL Server 2005. But the driver may not be for that.

Comment: i have added `sqljdbc4.jar` in the class path

Comment: I am using Eclipse Indigo IDE and i have already added `sqljdbc4.jar` to the buildpath of the project. Still i get the error.

Comment: Edited the answer try that and see.

Comment: you mean to change it in persistence.xml ? If so I tried that now but still the error remains.

Comment: I got the sqljdbc4.jar and checked I was wrong you have put the correct class there. In that case you need to open the SampleEAR.ear file with winrar or some other archive manager and see if it's available in there. If it's not You have not set the library properly.

Comment: i cant find SampleEAR.ear file

Comment: It's on you servers deploy folder. :-|